# How do I create a new folder in Mutt

Tags: mutt, courier

I want to create a  new folder from within Mutt.
I use Maildir format to store the folders on the machine I am running Mutt on.

*(I also view the mail remotely  using courier IMAP but this doesnt involve Mutt)*

**Edited** to clarify role of IMAP

Comment: I'm using Dovecot, and it supports activating the `imapd` directly from shell; for example, `dovecot --exec-mail imap`, which can be used for Mutt's `set tunnel=`. Maybe Courier has a similar thing too? It would allow mailbox creation within Mutt. (`/usr/lib/courier/imap` might be enough.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If Mutt cannot create maildirs directly, it is easy to do it yourself. A "Maildir" format mail directory has nothing special except for three subdirectories `cur/`, `new/` and  `tmp/` inside.

Assuming that your mail is kept under `~/mail/`, a folder named "Something" would be created like:

- For the Maildir++ layout used by Courier and Dovecot:

  ```
  mkdir -p ~/mail/.Something/{cur,new,tmp}
  ```

  (Note the leading dot – yes, this basically means subfolders are stored as hidden directories...)

  Equivalent to:

  ```
  mkdir ~/mail                    (implied by `-p`)
  mkdir ~/mail/.Something         (implied by `-p`)
  mkdir ~/mail/.Something/cur     (from brace expansion)
  mkdir ~/mail/.Something/new     (from brace expansion)
  mkdir ~/mail/.Something/tmp     (from brace expansion)
  ```
- For the "filesystem" layout used by some other IMAP daemons:

  ```
  mkdir -p ~/mail/Something/{cur,new,tmp}
  ```

If you want a folder hierarchy "Archive" / "2010" / "06":

- In Courier's layout, the folder would be named `Archive.2010.06`:

  ```
  mkdir -p ~/mail/.Archive.2010.06/{cur,new,tmp}
  ```
- In the "filesystem" layout, it would be `Archive/2010/06`:

  ```
  mkdir -p ~/mail/Archive/2010/06/{cur,new,tmp}
  ```

(Terminology: mail clients keep messages in 'folders', and the filesystem stores everything in 'directories'.)

Comment: Mutt will create a new mailbox when saving a message into a non-exiting one. When setting `set mbox_type=Maildir` in the configuration file, it will use the Maildir format.

Answer (score 18):

<kbd>c</kbd> (`change-folder`), <kbd>?</kbd> (list), <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (`create-mailbox`).

---

This works with Gmail but only in the single directory view, and not in the "all folders" view.

Also, if you want a space in the directory name, you need to escape it via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Comment: This only works across IMAP (i have reworded my question). I wonder if I ought to be using `maildirmake -f`

Comment: @justin: Posted other answer.

Comment: @grawity Agreed, edit has nothing to do with TLS, but mutt seems to have a quirk when creating a folder in the "all folders" view, and succeeds when utilizing a IMAP vs IMAP**s** (bug I should probably report).

Comment: I rarely create folders on IMAP servers but when I do, they usually have spaces in their name so I've been back to this answer more than once after discovering that escaping with a backslash or quotes doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

I usually just save some email to new not-yet-existing folder, and mutt creates the folder for me.

For me it's pretty intuitive, as there is no point in having folder without mails in it, so I just create it by saving there first mails that should go there.

Comment: How do you do that - if you type M it then gives me a list of existing mailboxes.  Thanks

Comment: "M"? I don't know what "M" does. I just press "s" on index of maildir, and then I can type my requested folder name.

Comment: @justintime `s`

Answer (score 4):

If you save a mail into a non-existing location, mutt creates a new mailbox for you. The type of the mailbox is determined by the state of the variable `mbox_type`. Hence, to create a Maildir within mutt, you proceed as follows.

Open your `.muttrc` file and add the line

```
set mbox_type=Maildir
```

This line ensures that mutt creates new mailboxes in the Maildir instead of in the Mbox format.

Then, start mutt and select a message that you want to save into a new folder. Press `s` to save and enter the path of the new mailbox (without a slash at the end) and press enter. Mutt will create a new Maildir and saves the message into the newly created mailbox.